# listbox selectedindex only selecting last element

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a listbox that is bound to a list of objects from the database. I have a secondary list that has less objects that I want to use it to mark as selected elements.

```
        cell = new HtmlTableCell();
        List<ClasaAutor> listaAutori = DataTableToClasaAutor(dal.CitesteTotiAutori());
        List<ClasaAutor> listaAutoriPublicatie = DataTableToClasaAutor(dal.CitesteTotiAutoriUneiPublicatii(guidPublicatie));
        ListBox list = new ListBox();
        list.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
        list.ID = "cbAutori";
        list.DataSource = listaAutori;
        list.DataTextField = "NumeComplet";
        list.DataValueField = "GuidAutor";
        list.DataBind();
        foreach (ClasaAutor autor in listaAutoriPublicatie)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list.Items[i].Value == autor.GuidAutor.ToString())
                    list.SelectedIndex = i;
            }
        }

        cell.Controls.Add(list);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
```

The problem is that only my last element gets selected... why? How can I fix it?

My `if` is ok, it gets true 2 times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this loop:

```
foreach (ClasaAutor autor in listaAutoriPublicatie)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in list.Items)
    {
        if (item.Value == autor.GuidAutor.ToString())
            item.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem in semantics, SelectedIndex of list can hold only one value, this is not collection

however you could make list item selected by setting the Selected value of it to true

```
 list.Items[i].Selected = list.Items[i].Value == autor.GuidAutor.ToString();
```